# React JS App with Firebase Remote Config for getting remote flags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I used [this document](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/create-feature-flags-for-your-react-app-with-firebase-remote-config-92d17c5e518d) for getting remote flags. I'm getting values and able to use in some components (not routing components). But In routed components like when I move from `"localhost/login"` to `"localhost/dashboard"` again firebase code is executing. Before it dashboard is loading and getting default values(empty). My intention is to get remote flags only one time before login and able to use those flags in entire app.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because remote flags data are stored only in the react state or inside the hook. Try using `Redux` to store the value by reducers in redux store. So then you will be able to access the value all over the App by accessing the store.

Please check this repo for your reference: https://github.com/kumarks1122/react-table

Comment: May I know is it possible without using `Redux`?